# Trying to create a heat map by region (Zip code) in Power Maps for Excel

Tags: mapping, office365, excel-2016

Is there a way to generate heat maps by zip code using Power Maps for Excel. I have build it using region and it does appear to have a heat map scaling for the color range. However the difference in the color range being used it not noticeable. So maybe I just need a way to adjust the color range.

I tried using the heat map option but all the zip codes have a ring for all the colors even though there is only one value per zip code. Also the zip codes blendtogether and form you giant blob of red.

If there is a different free option you would recommend for doing this type of mapping I am open to suggestions. I previously used MapPoint but that is no longer an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the look of your Power Map. You could also change the color for one or more data series.

Please refer to the following link:

[Geocode your Power Map data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/geocode-your-power-map-data-3857c274-1a44-4020-876a-398fecee70e7)

[Change the look of your Power Map](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-look-of-your-power-map-8ce6f8d3-f86d-467a-9031-750b3608a832#__add_map_labels)

[Change the color of a data series in 3D Maps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-color-of-a-data-series-in-3d-maps-ca7e3d6d-fe4e-4680-a96a-66261b6a490d)